# Function that sets an exponent in string in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I am looking for a function that does the following rending:

```
f("2") = 2²
f("15") = 2¹⁵
```

I tried `f(s) = "2\^($s)"` but this doesn't seem to be a valid exponent as I can't TAB.

Comment: Curious: what you need it for?

Comment: I used it to make the legend in the package [BenchmarkProfiles.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSmoothOptimizers/BenchmarkProfiles.jl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try e.g.:

```
julia> function f(s::AbstractString)
           codes = Dict(collect("1234567890") .=> collect("¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰"))
           return "2" * map(c -> codes[c], s)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f("2")
"2²"

julia> f("15")
"2¹⁵"
```

(I have not optimized it for speed, but I hope this is fast enough with the benefit of being easy to read the code)

Comment: One step better (possibly) is `codes = [x for x in "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"]` with `map(c -> codes[c-'0'+1], s)`

Comment: It would be faster to hardcode a tuple `('⁰', '¹', '²', '³', '⁴', '⁵', '⁶', '⁷', '⁸', '⁹')` as it would be non-allocating, but I thought it would be less clear.

Answer (score 1):

this should be a little faster, and uses `replace`:

```
function exp2text(x) 
  two = '2'
  exponents = ('⁰', '¹', '²', '³', '⁴', '⁵', '⁶', '⁷', '⁸', '⁹') 
  #'⁰':'⁹' does not contain the ranges 
  exp = replace(x,'0':'9' =>i ->exponents[Int(i)-48+1])
  #Int(i)-48+1 returns the number of the character if the character is a number
  return two * exp
end
```

in this case, i used the fact that `replace` can accept a `Pair{collection,function}` that does:

```
if char in collection
  replace(char,function(char))
end
```